# How change body's friction when contact with ground has begun?

Tags: box2d, libgdx, andengine

I making platformer character controls, something like this ->[BOX2D platformer](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2017)
I'm using ContactListener interface.
My problem is(friction) with these lines from code in the link ->

```
if(!grounded) {
    playerPhysicsFixture.setFriction(0f);
    playerSensorFixture.setFriction(0f);            
} else {
    if(!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) && stillTime > 0.2) {
        playerPhysicsFixture.setFriction(100f);
        playerSensorFixture.setFriction(100f);
    }
    else {
        playerPhysicsFixture.setFriction(0.2f);
        playerSensorFixture.setFriction(0.2f);
    }
}
```

I can't figure how to change friction when feet already in touch with ground. When I change the friction in onUpdate() method of my character, the friction of conact that already is started isn't changed. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From b2Fixture:

```
// Set the coefficient of friction. This will _not_ change the friction of
// existing contacts.
void SetFriction(float32 friction);
```

So you are completely correct. In a recent version of Box2D they added `Contact.setFriction()` to accompensate for that behaviour. I'm not sure in which version of libGDX this version of Box2D was added, but at least in the nightlies of libGDX these new methods are available.

So set the friction on the `Contact` in your `ContactListener`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but when I change the Contact it's not refresh before it ends. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Shaq I actually never had to use it myself that way. What I can read in the JavaDoc of Contact.setFriction is this: "Override the default friction mixture. You can call this in b2ContactListener::PreSolve. This value persists until set or reset.". Do you set it in PreSolve?

Comment: Thank you @noone, you saved my life. I know that I should avoid comment like this but, I'm very excited because it works. I was set it on preSolve(), but in wrong way. Now I have boolean variable with which I set the friction on preSolve().